# Create multiple pods from the same YAML definition file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So, I have a pod definition file and I was wondering if there was a way to use the kubectl apply command to create multiple instances of the pod from the same definition file. I know this can be done with a deployment but wondering if there was a way to quickly spin up multiple pods using the apply command?

Comment: Nope, they need a unique name. The easiest is to use `Deployment`.

Comment: @Jonas That's what i figured, but just wanted to check. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know this can be done with a deployment but wondering if there was a
> way to quickly spin up multiple pods using the apply command?

Yes, this is possible but not with the simple `kubectl apply` command as it doesn't have such options/capabilities and cannot be used to create multiple instances of a pod from a single yaml definition file.

If you just need to create **n number** of independent pods, not managed by any `replicaset`, `deployment`, `statefulset` etc., you can use for this purpose a simple bash one-liner.

Suppose we want to quickly spin up 10 independent pods based on the following yaml template, named `pod-template.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{pod-name}}
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

We can do it with the following script:

```
for i in {1..10}; do sed "s/{{pod-name}}/pod-$i/g" pod-template.yaml | kubectl apply -f - ; done
```

It will create 10 pods named `pod-1`, `pod-2` ... `pod-10`:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do sed "s/{{pod-name}}/pod-$i/g" pod-template.yaml | kubectl apply -f - ; done
pod/pod-1 created
pod/pod-2 created
pod/pod-3 created
pod/pod-4 created
pod/pod-5 created
pod/pod-6 created
pod/pod-7 created
pod/pod-8 created
pod/pod-9 created
pod/pod-10 created
```

And just in case you want to delete them now and don't want to do it one by one ;)

```
for i in {1..10};do kubectl delete pod pod-$i; done
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a cool way to do it (tho at that point I think it's easier to just use a deployment)..

Comment: Yes, everything depends on your particular use case. In fact it's very rare when we need to create Pods manually. Usually they are managed by `Deployment`, `Statefulset` or other controller. Exception is a [static pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/), directly managed by kubelet on particular worker node, but in most cases it can be substituted by a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

Comment: Yeah, in my case I was just testing out to see if a pod created outside of a deployment would be counted as part of a deployment as long as the selectors matched.. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way to use **deployment** only and for scaling you can simply use the **scale command** or implement HPA or VPA.

You can change the replicas count in deployment also to quickly spin up multiple pods.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  **replicas: 3**
```

Deployment in background use Replica sets or RC.

Comment: Yup, I know they can be scaled with deployments but I was wondering if it could be done  using just the pod definition file.

Answer (score 0):

if you want static name for pods then use statefulset for replica creattion.
for example, if you create 3 replicas the name will be like this ,
pod1: `statefulset_name-0`
pod2: `statefulset_name-1`
and so on.

you can do it with deployment also. but deployment will create a pod name with  random values after deployment.
here is the example for statefulset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
```

[Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#creating-a-statefulset)